# Universal Link not working

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I need to open my app from the email.
this is the email url: http://staging.imixedtape.com/accept_invite?token=be484a99b1f4554e42b7232dc2268c5e

And for this i need to integrate universal link in my app.
this is my apple-app-site-association file which opens via:
http://staging.imixedtape.com/apple-app-site-association

it returns:

```
{
  "applinks": {
  "apps": [],
  "details": [
    {
      "appID": "ZVDN92A33X.com.lemondeit.mixedtape",
      "paths": ["*"]
    }
  ]
   }
}
```

Still my app is not opening up from the link provided above.
I have added the domain "staging.imixedtape.com" in the associated domain capabilities tab.
I don't know what's left. also the apple-app-site-association file is uploded onto the root of the server.

Also i have edited my scheme to Release rather Debug, and i am testing it on the real device

Comment: Try Branch's validator: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/. See also questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811305/universal-links-not-working-in-development?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668

Comment: I did, and it doesn't validate. however the url with apple-app-site-association does return the json thing.

Comment: If you long tap on the link http://staging.imixedtape.com/accept_invite?token=be484a99b1f4554e42b7232dc2268c5e in Safari or in Notes App, do you have option "Open in APP_NAME?" Is ZVDN92A33X correct AppPrefixID (can be different from team ID)?

Comment: Nop! it just opens the webpage into safari

Comment: You mean there is no option  "Open in APP_NAME?" when long tapped? Or option is here but opens in Safari? If first try to reinstall the App. Also may consider increasing App version number to force refetch of the apple-app-site-association file. Recheck AppPrefixID.