# iOS 9.2+ Universal Linking redirect

Tags: ios, redirect, ios-universal-links

Im trying to get a universal link working to open a app if its installed.  I am using http://www.adjust.com in order to handle the internal redirecting to the app or store.  The problem I'm running into is that the server I'm using is redirecting it to the https://app.adjust.com/##### which is then redirecting to https://########.ulink.adjust.com(the universal link) which should open the app but it opens the store, even with the app installed.  The reason I think this is not working is a redirecting issue. If I simply click the https://########.ulink.adjust.com link it opens the app if its installed or store if not.  Any insight is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect to universal link from the browser, it would not work. It works only if you try to open link from another app, like Messages or Mail. If you want to open your app from browser you can use Custom URL Schemes ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)).
Also, here is a great tool to test universal links : https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com

Comment: what happens right now I click server link => that opens browser => that opens the  https://app.adjust.com/##### => redirects to universal => opens store.  Is that still not going to work?  what would you suggest a solution for this might be instead?

Comment: How universal links should work - you tap the link from any app - it opens you app. If you tap link from browser - it opens webpage, not the app. So in your case in first step it depends - are you open server link in browser or from some app.

Comment: the link from the server is being opened from Messages.

Comment: If you open link from Messages, it has to open your app, not the browser. Than means something goes wrong when you register associated domains.  Check these articles: 1) https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9 2) http://blog.hokolinks.com/how-to-implement-apple-universal-links-on-ios-9/ And this tool realy helps https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com

Comment: even if the link from the server is redirecting to a universal link? Or in this case sever link is redirecting to a redirect to a universal link

Comment: If you try to redirect, it looks like this: tap link on Messages > Safari opens > Redirecting > and now redirected URL opens in safari. Universal link doesn't work when you try to open it from Safari, so redirecting shouldn't work.

Comment: Would it work if I had a UL button on a page then had the user click that? Instead of doing all these redirects.

Comment: This case described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143553/ios9-universal-links-do-not-work-from-safari-but-works-from-other-apps

Answer (score 1):

Redirected Universal Link only works when click happens in Safari. Outside Safari, UL only works when it's directly clicked

Answer (score 0):

Universal links will not work with redirections. AppsFlyer has a solution that work redirecting to the App Store when the app is not installed.