# Differentiate requests from MobileSafari vs. SafariViewController

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

For a web application, is there a way (either client- or server-side) to differentiate requests coming from MobileSafari vs. SafariViewController (embedded in any 3rd party app)?

I need this because SafariViewController doesn't support universal links and smart app banners so I'd like to show an appropriate alternative in the content.

I've checked the HTTP User-Agent and it's exactly the same for both.

Comment: What does this fiddle demo report: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/6qrbn/

Comment: @LGSon 'browser' for both.

Comment: Ok, have you tested the [navigator objects properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) and if they differ between the two? ... (I can't test as I don' have either browser/device)

Comment: Here are 2 more links that might help, 1: [ios9-universal-links-does-not-work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751225/ios9-universal-links-does-not-work) ....2: [css-hack-for-safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Comment: I've checked the CSS test page http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html#webkit and the JS test page https://www.cyscape.com/showbrow.asp?bhcp=1 and they yield the exact same output. Only the `HeightAvail` property differs (1649 in TweetBot SafariVC, 1487 in MobileSafari). But I assume this property might even change from one SafariVC instance to another.

Comment: I spend some time try find how to detect SafariViewController but came up short. Can't you test the link result somehow and see if what should be in there is present?

Comment: The smart app banner and the small banner for universal links aren't part of the DOM. Safari seems to render them natively, independent of the HTML. So I don't see a way how to find out if they're shown or not.

Comment: Maybe testing for URL schema? http://stephenradford.me/link-to-url-scheme-or-not-and-force-out-of-the-app-youre-in/

Comment: @catlan I believe I can only open a URL directly but not really test if it can open it (the trick is to open a second URL with a timeout if the first open didn't succeed). However, in that regard, Safari and SafariVC seem to behave identically, too. Of course I could ditch smart app banners and Universal Links completely and try to open the URL scheme directly in order to open in-app. However I don't really like this approach and prefer to let the user decide where to open it.

Comment: I made this for test, any of these props. that can be useful? ... https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/L4bu8smL/

Comment: @LGSon all properties are equal. :(

Answer (score 1):

There's no official/"production ready" way to detect the difference. However, there are some obscure system font differences. For example, in SFSafariViewController there is a system font, `.Helvetica LT MM`. It might break in a future iOS release though.

Here's some code to detect that system font:

https://gist.github.com/aeharding/08eaafbb7742f78ede9b8d2f5d096354

Answer (score -2):

Instead of testing for the specific client, you should test for functionality. Check out Modernizr https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

If you ask the question that way "How do I detect for universal links and smart app banners" that will be a more useful question for modern web app development than sniffing specific clients.

Comment: With respect, this is not an answer to my question. You can debate the usefulness of a question by posting a comment (or even downvote a question) but an answer should actually solve the OP's question.