# Apple Universal Link not working always

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

I started my applicaiton, its open an url in safari. On my website the user can login and do some work. After the user did it the website redirect to the universal link. At first it is working fine, but if the user start again my application, open my website from it (the safari already show my website), login again and redirect to the universal link, show the universal link, and on the top I see a bar where i can open my application.

If the user didn't login to my website, just clicked on the button to redirect to my universal link the ios9 open my application.

Have you got any idea, what's wrong? Maybe the iOS 9 doesn't like the autoredirect to universal link?

Answer (score 0):

Universal links does not work with redirections.

Comment: But why it is working if i redirect the user to universal link after the user click on the redirect button? and it is not working if i autoredirect the user to universal link..

Answer (score 0):

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751734/127493

I just been on a similar issue where I clicked the link on the top right side of the screen, disabling the automatic opening in my app.
since you see the banner, the user has to scroll a bit (to show the banner "open" ) and all redirections will occcur on your app again (and not safari)