# Uber deep link worked perfect and then stopped working

Tags: uber-api

I added a uber link button to my web app that passes my current location for pickup and a dropoff address to the app. I tested it on Saturday and it worked. I clicked the button, the uber app on my iPhone opened immediately with my current location as the pickup address and the address I passed in as the dropoff. I'm sending latitude and longitude as well as text address. It was working perfectly.

Now, since Monday, the same code is doing something different; even when I send the exact request. Now I get, "This site is attempting to open a pop-up window". I click "Allow". Then I get, "Open this page in "App Store". I click "Open" and it brings up the Uber app in the app store. From there I click OPEN. It opens the app, but the pickup and dropoff addresses are not being passed in.

I've tried different addresses and get the same result. Here's the link I'm sending (I removed my client ID for this post).

https://m.uber.com/ul?client_id=xxxxxxx&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=33.392117&dropoff[longitude]=-112.000173&dropoff[formatted_address]=3747%20E.%20Southern%20Avenue%20Phoenix,%20AZ,%2085040

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is the deeplink a documented feature or not? If it's not a documented feature, this probably isn't a good question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes it's documented here https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking-universal-links

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you forced the link to open in Safari at some point? The universal link remembers how you last opened it and tries to do that again. So in this case, it seems like it's trying to open it in Safari, which goes to a page that redirects to the App Store, rather than opening the native Uber app.

If that's the case you can long press on your button and you should see an option to 'Open in "Uber"' If you tap that, it should work as expected (and continue to for future taps)

Take a look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751225/ios9-universal-links-does-not-work/32751734#comment53382074_32751734)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's possible that my phone is stuck redirecting to Safari, but i'm using an HTML input button. There's no long press event. Do you know of any other way to change the default back to launch the app?

Comment: If you tap cancel when it tries to redirect to the App Store it will redirect to a web page. Scroll up on that page and you should see a banner to open it in the Uber app, tap on that and it should remember it for the future

Comment: That worked! It was a little tricky because that screen flashed and disappeared really fast when I clicked cancel. But after a few tries, I got it to stay. Then I clicked the banner and it went right to the app. Now my button opens the app like it should. Thank you so much for your help!