# Does DeepLinking apple-app-site-association file need signing?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep linking. I have followed the documentation and created the 'apple-app-site-association' file and very sure there is no mistake in the file format. The file has been placed in the root directory as well as the backend side.

My domain does not use https, only http. Does the file need to be signed irrespective of this?
Following is the apple doc which I used for reference [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) 
I have read that there is no need to sign the apple-app-site-association file.
I am perplexed as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

When using HTTP, I think the answer may be yes. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) says that you don't need to sign the `apple-app-site-association` file if you *are* using HTTPS:

[image]

This leads me to believe that you may need to sign it if you are using HTTP. [Apple's Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) may be helpful to test this.

If you're still having problems after getting past the validator, see [iOS9: Universal Links does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751225/ios9-universal-links-does-not-work/33304998#33304998), which has many good answers about the many things that can go wrong with deep linking.

Comment: will try signing the file , lets see if that does the trick.Thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you are not serving the file over a HTTPS connection, it must be signed

Comment: Could you please let me know  i how should  sign the apple-app-site-association file . Iam unable to find any resources in regard to this