# iOS universal links not working?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-universal-links

I'm having trouble getting universal links to work

- We have added the json content to our site https://couchsurfing.com/apple-app-site-association
- I have double checked that it's using the correct team ID and bundle ID
- Universal links is enabled in itunesConnect

running the apple validation fails with the following error:
**Error no apps associated with url**

I thought maybe the validator doesn't work, but running on iOS 10 device (universal link capability on, with added correct domain to it) clicking a valid link does not trigger the delegate methods in AppDelegate

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751225/ios-universal-links-are-not-opening-in-app/66353132#66353132

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After 3 weeks... It turned out my path was incorrect. My suggestion:

set paths to `["*", "/"]` while debugging, get everything to work and test, then as the final step update the path and only include supported paths.

To be more specific the link I was trying to register was
`site.com/events/123123` so I would add a path for `/events` which is wrong that would register `site.com/events`. I had to register `/events/*` instead

Also the easiest way to test it is to enter the expected links into the `Notes` app, because Safari has some weird logic on when links should be handled as deeplink.

Apple's app-site-association validator is useless, it's still failing for me complaining about my App id, when deeplinks actually work. Instead use https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This here: "/events/*" is the MOST important information ever!

Comment: Wow!  What you said about the Notes app and Safari's weird logic was really true!  My code had been already correct.  When I tried Notes, my app started loading every time.  It had never loaded before.  I hope what you said only applies to the Safari address bar and that links Safari finds on pages will work okay.

Comment: I also was breaking my brain over the safari weird logic issue. Copying my test link to notes did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that "/events/*" won't work for "site.com/events/123123/something", because asterisk only works within a single path component. This was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently had issues debugging the *Universal Link* functionality of my app. 
I was able to get deep linking to work but it seemed to only work 10% of the time. Since I had just updated to *iOS 12*, I wanted to make sure there was nothing else I had to do as a developer to ensure the feature worked.

So what was causing intermittent failure? 
It seems that iOS has a somewhat strict policy engine for determining when background threads can run. 
I was able to observe this by USB tethering to my phone and opening up the debug console for my device

- Xcode –> Windows –> Devices & Simulators
- Click on device in the left pane
- Click *Open Console*

From there, I was able to filter on "*swcd*" (*SharedWebCredential Daemon*). Keeping this console open, I was able to see the daemon at work during app install which is when iOS attempts to pull down the *apple-app-site-association* file for my app.

As it turns out, *dasd* (*DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon*) was failing to run the *SharedWebCredential Daemon* because my phone had restarted recently, then later it was determined that my phone was too hot...

e.g.

```
{name: ThunderingHerdPolicy, policyWeight: 1.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceInUse == 1 AND timeSinceThunderingHerdTriggerEvent < 900}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}

{name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 20}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
```

Developers beware!

Comment: That's quite interesting. What else did you find?

Comment: Incredibly useful feedback here. On my first try, I actually saw the request succeed. Logs were (some info redacted): `default 17:01:41.239379 -0700 swcd Added service 'applinks', appID 'XXXXXXXX.com.example-sandbox', domain 'www.example-sandbox.com'`

Comment: Also, the remove, reboot, reinstall process was necessary for this to finally work: https://blog.branch.io/notice-inconsistent-universal-link-behavior-on-ios-11-2/

Comment: This was written about a year ago.  I'm trying to get it to work now.  Can it really be that flaky?  Maybe I'm doing everything right and it still isn't working simply because I haven't tried enough times.

Comment: I got below error when install the application (iPhone 7 plus, iOS 13.3.1)

Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal: Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=250, Function=<private>}

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I step through Apple's [troubleshooting universal links procedure](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html) as already mentioned in other answers.

If still not working, and long-pressing the link in mail or notes app fails to show "Open with [your app]" then **try restarting your phone**. More than a few times this has been the solution for me!

Comment: I didn't believe, but restart helped.

Comment: Ridiculous isn’t it?

Answer (score 3):

The Apple validator checks some other things that are not necessary for Universal Links to work, and unfortunately that often results on false positive error messages. The file at https://couchsurfing.com/apple-app-site-association looks good to me, and it passes [this validator](https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/) just fine.

When clicking on a valid link, does the app *not open*, or just the delegate methods don't fire? These are two very different issues and would have different solutions. There are some troubleshooting steps you could try [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links), though some of those are specific to the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) linking platform.

Comment: no the app doesn't open  and delegate methods are not called, been stuck on this for 2 weeks :( gone through that troubleshooting guide already

Answer (score 1):

As some sort of completion to the answers above (took me hours to find out):

The app needs to be installed AFTER you added your "apple-app-site-association" file to the server, as the file initially got fetched / checked after the installation.