# How to get universal link url into iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am using Universal linking in my application.

**I want the functionality like this:-**

Enable Associated domains in both Xcode and developer account.

Xcode associated domain contains:  applinks:laundry.com

Push apple-app-site-association into server with code :

```
{"applinks": {"apps": [],
              "details": [{"paths": ["*"],
              "appID": "Sm4Gn629J2.com.LaundryLive"}]}}
```

This is the code used in AppDelegate class, but it is not working. Please help me.

```
//Universal links in swift delegatemethod.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
            let userurl = url.absoluteString
            // print(url.absoluteString)
            //handle url
            if userurl != "", defaultValues.value(forKey: accessToken) != nil
            {
                print("user url is:",userurl)
                let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Pickup", bundle: nil)

                let innerPage: PickupController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickupController") as! PickupController
                innerPage.selectedfrom = "Deeplink"
                self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
            }else{
                setRootControllerBeforeLogin()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Is laundry.com correct?

Comment: please double check the possible issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751734/1302999

Comment: yes domain is correct I give my own domain that place.

Comment: Check in the [Apple validator](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool)