# How to prevent iOS Safari alert when trying to open non-installed native app in iOS 9

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, ios9

Hello I want to open application from safari.

1. App Installed : app will get opened instantly ... I try on load as well as after 30 seconds again using timeOut function.
2. If App is not installed It will try point 1 so there is no app it will make alert "Cannot Open Page , Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid." ...

I know in IOS 9 there is IFRAME way it works like charm but in IOS 9 it is not working.

I've read this question and answers..

1. [Opening apps from Safari with iOS 9 Universal Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148821/opening-apps-from-safari-with-ios-9-universal-links)
2. [how to prevent iOS safari alert when trying to open non-installed native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701708/how-to-prevent-ios-safari-alert-when-trying-to-open-non-installed-native-app)